# i'm getting isssue while calling API in Useeffect in reactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, frontend

I'm calling two methods in useeffect but when **api1** get called it get executed till  **await axios.put** and then **api2** get called without getting the response from **api1**. And after getting a reponse from **api2** it goes to api1 reponse and gets a reponse as **undefined**

```
useEffect(() => {       
          api1();
       api2();
    }, [])

const api1 = async () => {
        try {
            var requestModel = JSON.stringify({ UserId: userid, MenuName: menuname });
            var requestBody = security.encrypt(requestModel);
            axios.myHashData = security.computedHmac256(requestBody);
            var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } }
            await axios.put(axios.controllername + 'methodname', requestBody, config, { withCredentials: true })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        //setapidata(response.data);
                    }
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message)
        }
    }
 const api2= async () => {
        try {
            var requestModel = JSON.stringify({ UserID: userid });
            var requestBody = security.encrypt(requestModel);
            axios.myHashData = security.computedHmac256(requestBody);
            var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } }
            await axios.post(axios.controllername + 'methodname', requestBody, config, { withCredentials: true })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        setapidata(response.data);
                        GetApis();
                    }
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It isn't very clear where your API functions get called from, or what response they're trying to use. Besides, if `api2` should be called after `api1` with data from `api1`, why not call it in `api1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the `api1` to execute before `api2` is called you need to change the code for useEffect as below

```
useEffect(async() => {
  await api1();
  await api2();
}, [])
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
  api1().then(() => api2());
}, [])
```

To handle errors properly use try-catch block inside the `useEffect` if using await or use `catch` block if using `.then`

Also, another suggestion, if you are using a function inside `useEffect` make sure either the function is defined inside the same `useEffect` block or it is memorized either via `useCallback` or `useMemo`